# How do you access values injected into HTML templates using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I have an HTML template with a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="some_{{model.property}}_{{other.value}}_text"></div>
```

I want to use JavaScript in my backbone view to dynamically format those injected values so that the IDs don't have spaces and slashes, etc. problem is that I don't know the right syntax to grab them. Right now I am doing this:

```
var unformatted = "some_{{model.property}}_{{other.value}}_text"
```

And then using jquery to set the id to a formatted value:

```
$('.common-class').attr('id', unformatted.formatMe());
```

It is, of course, giving me the literal string value with the curly brackets and path to the data. How can I get to the values instead? I am using backbone, marionette, require, bootstrap, and Spring with JSPs on the backend. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to do this *before* the values are injected and you attempt to add a fragment of invalid markup to the DOM. It's too late to do it afterwards, you cannot query an element by an ID with a space in it because that is not a valid ID in the first place. In Backbone, you would do this in your model's render method. We can't really tell you more unless you show us your `render`.

Comment: Instead of trying to stuff data into the id field to later parse out, use other fields such as data fields.  <div data-whatevermodelproperty="insert your model.property value here" data-othervalueproperty="insert your other.value here"></div>  then access them with $('.common-class').data('whatevermodelproperty') and $('.common-class').data('othervalueproperty')

Comment: Actually it is in the onrender function where I am making these changes. I am making it from scratch though so all I have at the moment is exactly what I have written above. Do I need to set those values at the scope of the onrender function?

Comment: I agree. But I don't actually have control over how that data gets pulled in, because other things (tracking, etc.) depend on the id's holding that info.

Comment: I am not sure but we may be

Comment: It's underscore but we are overriding the syntax

Answer (score 0):

@meagar is correct. You should create the properties that you want before rendering the template. The template should reference the new value and not the original model property.

```
<div id="{{newValue}}"></div>
```

If, for example, you want to modify or change `someProperty` so that it is rendered as `newValue`, you could simply add `newValue` as an additional model property.

```
render: function() {
    this.model.set('newValue', computeNewValue(someProperty));
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
}
```

If you don't want the `newValue` attribute polluting your model, you can simply add it to the object passed to the template:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(
        _(this.model.toJSON()).extend({
            newValue: computeNewValue(someProperty)
        })
    ));
}
```

In the latter case, the model itself isn't modified, but the template is able to access the computed value.